# How to create Aweber subscribers with subscribed status

Tags: php, api, aweber

I am implementing this Aweber API: https://labs.aweber.com/  to add subscribers to a list with PHP language, subscribers are adding successfully, but I want to add with "subscribed" status, they are currently adding with "unconfirmed"  status.

Could you please help me how can I add subscribers with subscribed status?

Comment: have you tried "status" with value "1" or "1001" in your API call?

Comment: Yes I tried, it is adding with "Confirmation Pending" status

Comment: ok, do one thing, assign "1" or "1001" to "ad_tracking" in API call

Comment: No, still same result

Answer (score 0):

By default, AWeber will always add subscribers in the API using a double opt in confirmation message. Once the subscriber finds the confirmation email that is automatically sent to them and clicks on the link within, they will change to "subscribed" status. If they do not confirm, they will automatically be removed after 30 days.

To change this setting, you need to contact AWeber's support team as that setting is not able to be changed by the API user. They can be contacted as described here:
https://www.aweber.com/contact-us.htm

Once the confirmation setting is turned off, subscribers will be added in the "subscribed" status instead of confirmation pending.