# Add subscriber to aweber list using API without confirmation email

Tags: php, aweber

I am using Aweber SDK to work with it's API. I am trying to add subscriber using API to aweber list but everytime I am adding subscriber, it is sending confirmation email to user and if user confirm it then only it is adding subscriber in the list. I want to add subscriber without sending confirmation email. Is there any parameter that I need to pass to aweber API.

Here is my code

```
$list = 'Test List';
$data = array(
        'email' => 'nadsoft.test01@gmail.com',
        'name' => 'Nadsoft test',
);

$aweber->addSubscriber($data, $list);
```

Please let me know if there is any extra parameter that I need to send to avoid confirmation.

Comment: This [post is a dup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45706278/1270789), but there's no approved answer there.

Comment: @KenY-N that's why I asked this question again and when I added the question, it did not show me that question.

Answer (score 1):

Most API submissions to AWeber will send a confirmation email. Some well know API integrations do not send a confirmation email: https://help.aweber.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002536994-Can-I-disable-confirmed-opt-in-for-my-integrations- .

> If you do not see your integration listed above and want confirmed
>       opt-in disabled for an integration, you can contact our customer
>       support team

https://www.aweber.com/contact-us.htm